# how to assign 0 to index which doesn't exist in result data frame in Panda

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate the confusion matrix myself (without using sklearn) for a dataset and to do that I used to `condition` and `values` as showed below:

```
conditions = [
    (df_a['y']== 1) & (df_a['y_hat']== 1),
    (df_a['y']== 1) & (df_a['y_hat']== 0),
    (df_a['y']== 0) & (df_a['y_hat']== 0),
    (df_a['y']== 0) & (df_a['y_hat']== 1),
    ]

# create a list of the values we want to assign for each condition
values = ['TP', 'FN', 'TN', 'FP']

# create a new column and use np.select to assign values to it using our lists as arguments
df_a['confusion_status'] = np.select(conditions, values)

# display updated DataFrame
result = df_a['confusion_status'].value_counts().rename_axis('unique_values').to_frame('counts') #counting values
result
```

The result of this operation for my dataset is:

```
                 counts
unique_values   
TP               10000
FP               100
```

In the above result, I don't have TN and FN because the main dataset didn't have such a result

Now I want to extract the result in a form of **actual number** and assign it to variable "TP","TN", "FP" and "FN". If the value does exist (in this case, for example for TN and FN), I want to get 0.

I tried using `iloc` to extract values like

```
result.loc["TP"]
```

but this doens't retun one number. Also, this won't cover missing values like TN, and FN for which I want to see 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part 1, you need to specify the column you want:

```
result.loc["TP","counts"]
```

For part 2, you'll need to check for presence:

```
if 'TN' in result.index:
```

Or, to patch any values not present

```
for v in values:
    if v not in result:
        result.loc[v,"counts"] = 0
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want to check all these together, from the beginning I don't know if TN will or will not be in my result, so how should I consider this? writing one universal "if-else" condition where if for example TN exists then "result.loc["TN","counts"]" and if not, then 0?